# Replacing Logical Operators in R

Tags: r, rcpp

A missing value (NA) is one whose value is unknown. Hence, for logical operators in R, if any missing exists it will never return TRUE or FALSE, only NA. However, I would like to change such behavior so instead of returning NA it returns FALSE. See the example below.

```
1 > 2
FALSE

1 > NA
NA
```

When asking if `1 > NA` I want the result to be `FALSE` instead of `NA`. To accomplish that, I had to write the following function using **Rcpp** and replace the R `>` for its new version that uses the **Rcpp** function called ***RcppOP***.

```
library("Rcpp")
RcppOP <- function(x, y, op) {
  # op == 1: greater than
  # op == 2: greater than or equals
  # op == 3: less than
  # op == 4: less than or equals
  # op == 5: equals
  # op == 6: different
  n <- max(length(x), length(y))
  nx <- length(x)
  ny <- length(y)
  if (nx == ny) {
    x1 <- x;
    y1 <- y;
  } else if (nx %% ny == 0) {
    x1 <- rep_len(x, n);
    y1 <- rep_len(y, n);
  } else if (ny %% nx == 0) {
    x1 <- rep_len(x, n);
    y1 <- rep_len(y, n);
  } else {
    warning("longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length")
    x1 <- rep_len(x, n);
    y1 <- rep_len(y, n);
  }
  cppFunction('LogicalVector opFun(NumericVector x, NumericVector y, int op, int n) {
  LogicalVector out(n);
  if (op == 1) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] > y[i];
    }
  }
  if (op == 2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] >= y[i];
    }
  }
  if (op == 3) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] < y[i];
    }
  }
  if (op == 4) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] <= y[i];
    }
  }
  if (op == 5) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] == y[i];
    }
  }
  if (op == 6) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      out[i] = x[i] != y[i];
    }
  }
  return out;
  }')
  opFun(x1, y1, op, n)
}

# greater than
`>` <- function(x, y) {
  RcppOP(x,  y, 1)
}
```

Now, if I run `1 > NA` it will return FALSE.

I am not an **Rcpp** expert and I wonder if someone could give me some feedback and help to improve it. Or let me know if this behavior can be changed without replacing the current R logical operators.

Thank you.

Comment: You absolutely do *not* need Rcpp to achieve that. That being said, changing the semantics of these operators *will* break existing code — it’s a terrible idea.

Comment: If the code works as intended, than this may more suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @qwerty I don’t think it belongs there since the code is, in fact, broken (for instance it now only handles numeric values, it will crash for anything else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph could you give an example on how to achieve that without usint Rcpp? I need it because the R operators are written in C.

Comment: @FernandoBritoLopes Nothing in your C++ code couldn’t be equally written in R. You just need to take care not to become recursive. You could do this, for instance, by starting your function by introducing local aliases (`\`<\` = base::\`<\``, etc.). But see my previous comments regarding whether that’s a good idea.

Comment: You could use `dplyr`'s `coalesce`-function: `my_fun <- function(x, y) dplyr::coalesce(x > y, FALSE)`. But usally it's a good idea to follow Konrad's advices. ;-)

Comment: Use `isTRUE()` in R and `is_true()` in Rcpp.

Answer (score 1):

All sorts of existing functions in R depend on the existing NA propagation behavior. A much simpler and safer approach, therefore, is to handle this issue at the level of data by replacing NA values with FALSE:

```r
data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), 
  b = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE)
) |> tidyr::replace_na(replace = list(a = NA, b = FALSE))
#>    a     b
#> 1  1  TRUE
#> 2  2 FALSE
#> 3  3 FALSE
#> 4 NA  TRUE

library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, 3, NA), 
  b = c(TRUE, FALSE, NA, TRUE)
) |> 
  mutate(across(where(is.logical), \(x) if_else(is.na(x), FALSE, x)))
#>    a     b
#> 1  1  TRUE
#> 2  2 FALSE
#> 3  3 FALSE
#> 4 NA  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Or use `coalesce`.